# Failing to convert a Char array to String

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get the current date and store it in a String, however when I attempt to save from a char array to the String, I receive the following error;

```
Error: Call of an object of a class type without appropriate operator() or conversion functions to pointer-to-function type in [file].
```

Yet I'm stumped as to why it does not work, as the function should work as used, according to the C++ references, as far as I'm aware. Code below.

```
#include <string>

...

std::string dummyString;
time_t tempTime;
struct tm * timeInfo;
char buffer [40];

tempTime = recordInstance->getTime();
timeInfo = localtime (&tempTime);

strftime (buffer, 80,"%d/%b/%Y",timeInfo);
dummyString(buffer); //Error returned on this line.
```

Comment: ...and what is dummyString? (Hint: It's not a function)

Comment: You declare `dummyString` to be a variable, and then surprisingly call it like a function?

Comment: My bad, forgot to include it because it was declared slightly earlier in the function. It's a string.

Comment: dummyString = std::move(std::string(buffer));

Comment: @DAG `std::move` is unnecessary as `std::string(buffer)` is already an rvalue. If you're going to do an assignment involving a null terminated string just use `dummyString = buffer`. Accomplishes the same thing in less steps and is much easier to read.

Comment: @Captain Obvlious exactly

Answer (score 2):

You obviously meant to write

```
dummyString=buffer;
```

instead of the last line in your shown code.

Comment: Oops, thank you. Can you only use "string(char[])" on initialisation of the string then?

Comment: @Potatosaurus -- yes, that's right: you can only use a constructor when you create an object. And that's why you shouldn't create objects until you're ready to initialize them. `std::string dummyString(buffer);` and not `std::string dummyString; ... dummyString = buffer;`.

Comment: Thanks again, stupid mistake now that I think about it.

Answer (score 2):

After looking at your question again there's something else I should mention as it's likely relevant here. Constructors are special unnamed member functions and cannot be invoked directly like other functions. They are only invoked when an object is first constructed and cannot be invoked again. If that was your intention now you have a better idea of why it won't work.

---

The error you get is because your code is trying to invoke `dummyString` as if it were a function. Although C++ *does* support the ability to do this the definition of `string` does not (there's no reason to - it's not a function type object). Based on your post it looks like you are attempting to construct `dummyString` well after it has been defined. It's definitely considered good practice to define a variable as close as possible to it's first use but this isn't how to do it.

When you define a variable it is initialized in some way. In this case the following statement causes the default constructor of `std::string` to be invoked on `dummyString`.

```
std::string dummyString;
```

What you are trying to do is construct `dummyString` using the contents of a character buffer. To do this you need to pass the string as an argument at the time of instantiation which in this case is when the variable is defined.

```
std::string dummyString(buffer);
```

This will construct the string using the contents of buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the issue is that the syntax:

dummyString(Char*) is a constructor -- but it looks like you've already declared dummyString somewhere?

Try declarying dummyString as...
string dummyString(buffer);

or if it must already be declared, try...

dummyString = buffer;

Answer (score 0):

Did you intend to do

```
dummyString = std::string(buffer);
```

or

```
dummyString = buffer;
```

because the syntax that you used is only allowed at time of declaration

```
std::string dummyString(buffer);
```